# How to create a correct (grayscale) PDF/X-3 file using Ghostscript

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, color-profiles, icc

I’m trying to convert arbitrary PDF files (a magazine created with pdfLaTeX, containing some photos, but also some graphics such as webcomics) to valid PDF/X-3 using Ghostscript and I want the result to be in grayscale/monochrome.
I don’t know a lot about ICC color profiles and *I don’t really care about color management* in any case, so if this easier without ICC profiles, then I don’t mind.
I’m willing to let the printer do their thing with my file – I don’t need absolute color fidelity (especially since we’re talking about grayscale here).

I’ve been trying to get it to work using the [Ghostscript documentation, section “Creating a PDF/X-3 document”](http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/VectorDevices.htm#PDFX).
Based on that, my attempt looks like this:

```
gs                                   \
  -dSAFER -sDEVICE=pdfwrite          \
  -dEmbedAllFonts                    \
  -sProcessColorModel=DeviceGray     \
  -sColorConversionStrategy=Gray     \
  -dPDFX -dPDFACompatibilityPolicy=1 \
  -o 'output.pdf' -f 'my_pdfx_def.ps' 'input.pdf'
```

Where `my_pdfx_def.ps` contains the following, based on the template that comes with Ghostscript:

```
%!

systemdict /ProcessColorModel known {
  systemdict /ProcessColorModel get dup /DeviceGray ne exch /DeviceCMYK ne and
} {
  true
} ifelse
{ (ERROR: ProcessColorModel must be /DeviceGray or /DeviceCMYK.)=
  /ProcessColorModel cvx /rangecheck signalerror
} if

[ /GTS_PDFXVersion (PDF/X-3:2002) % Must be so (the standard requires).
  /Trapped /False                 % Must be so (Ghostscript doesn't provide other).
  /DOCINFO pdfmark

% Define an ICC profile:

currentdict /ICCProfile known {
  [/_objdef {icc_PDFX} /type /stream /OBJ pdfmark
  [{icc_PDFX} <</N systemdict /ProcessColorModel get /DeviceGray eq {1} {4} ifelse >> /PUT pdfmark
  [{icc_PDFX} ICCProfile (r) file /PUT pdfmark
} if

% Define the output intent dictionary:

[/_objdef {OutputIntent_PDFX} /type /dict /OBJ pdfmark
[{OutputIntent_PDFX} <<
  /Type /OutputIntent              % Must be so (the standard requires).
  /S /GTS_PDFX                     % Must be so (the standard requires).
  /OutputCondition (Commercial and specialty printing) % Customize
  /Info (none)                     % Customize
  /OutputConditionIdentifier (CGATS TR001)      % Customize
  /RegistryName (http://www.color.org)   % Must be so (the standard requires).
  currentdict /ICCProfile known {
    /DestOutputProfile {icc_PDFX}  % Must be so (see above).
  } if
>> /PUT pdfmark
[{Catalog} <</OutputIntents [ {OutputIntent_PDFX} ]>> /PUT pdfmark
```

This does run and produces a file that superficially seems OK in my PDF viewer.
However, I’m not sure that this is actually enough (producing a valid/sensible PDF/X-3 document) considering the long list of things I’m supposed to do according to Ghostscript’s documentation.
In particular, it says

> To create a PDF/X-3 document from a Postscript or a PDF file, you should :
>
> […]
>
> - Specify a PDF/X definition file before running the input document. It provides additional information to be included into the output document. A sample PDF/X definition file may be found in `gs/lib/PDFX_def.ps`.
> - If a registered printing condition is applicable, specify its identifier in the PDF/X definition file. Otherwise provide an ICC profile and specify it in the PDF/X definition file as explained below.

I tried adapting the file `PDFX_def.ps` it mentions (see above), but I don’t know what an `OutputCondition` is or what I’m supposed to put for that.
Unfortunately, this is barely documented in the Ghostscript docs.
I tried setting an `.icc` file in my customized version, but couldn’t get Ghostscript to find that file – no matter what, I always got “`Error: /invalidfileaccess in --file--`”.
And which color profile would I be using, anyway?

> - Provide a `DefaultRGB` resource file in the ColorSpace resource category. Either define it in the PDF/X definition file, or provide a definition of `gs/Resource/ColorSpace/DefaultRGB`. `gs/Resource/ColorSpace/DefaultRGB` is usually distributed with Ghostscript, its content may not necessarily satisfy your needs, see below.

Needless to say, it doesn’t specify how to do this.
But in any case, do I even need this considering I want grayscale?

> - Specify, using `-sOutputICCProfile`, an ICC profile which represents the color space (either CMYK or Gray) of the final file. This is the same ICC profile used in the PDF/X definition file as the ICCProfile. Even if you are using a standard `OutputCondition` and do not need to specify an ICCProfile, you must still set `OutputICCProfile` with an appropriate ICC profile in order for proper color conversion.

Well, I didn’t specify `-sOutputICCProfile` and that didn’t seem to do any harm.
Should I still?
(Again, where am I supposed to pull the ICC profile out from?)

Comment: I tried your code but had to add `-I ./` in the `gs` command to fix the `/invalidfileaccess in --file--` error.